# Cycle holidays with kids in Poland

Tags: children, poland, bicycles, outdoor-activities

I would like to plan cycling holidays with kids in Poland for the summer. Because the kids are still very small I have pretty restrictive requirements:

1. We need to avoid public roads with car traffic (because of obvious safety requirements).
2. The trails need to be easy, with even surface and little differences in elevation.
3. Ideally we would like a variety of trails in a single location.
4. And the area should be nice, preferably outdoors (as opposed to cities/towns).

I am seriously struggling to find any materials or guides to help pick a location. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for a holiday in Poland? From what you ask I thought you were looking for a cycling holiday in Holand.

Comment: @Willeke, a nice one, rotfl...

Comment: Try something near the odra, with a bridge. Sleep and eat in Poland, cycle in Germany :D I did a tour there once between Frankfurt nad Odra and Swinoujscie, and the German side has good and quiet roads, and the trails along the river are really easy.

Answer (score 3):

Your profile says you live in Poland, so you should be aware that nice bikepaths don't exist here :) .
However, I think you could try out some sea side area (should be pretty flat), [Słowiński Park Narodowy](http://www.czasnarower.pl/trasy/tag/slowinski_park_narodowy) for example.

I've never been there, but heard about it to be nice bike-friendly area.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do your own legwork, but [a simply Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cycling%20holiday%20poland) returns plenty of websites offering cycling holidays in Poland and, presumably access to experts.

Here are a few:

- [Wheel2Wheel](http://wheel2wheelholidays.com/cycling-holidays-in-poland)
- [Cycling Poland](http://www.cyclingpoland.com)
- [cycling.pl](http://cycling.pl/index.php?id=29)
- [biketours.com](https://www.biketours.com/poland/)

Comment: I couldn't find any that would specialize in holidays with kids. The fact that you are travelling with kids *does make a lot of difference*.

Comment: Of course it does. Did you try contacting some of these outfits, asking if they had suggestions for when traveling with kids?